# php sends normal time but mysql inserts 00:00:08 into table which is wrong

Tags: php, mysql

`date('H-m-s')` gives something like this when I echo variable > `08-07-16`

I have table in mysql and the field type is set to TIME.

And when I transfer this data there, in mysql table I see this > `00:00:08`

I repeat it several times but I see only this > `00:00:08`

What's the problem with mysql ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL's TIME type expects the time in the format `HH:MM:SS`.  Generate your date in PHP as:

```
date("H:i:s");
```

Or as eykanal points out, use the `DATETIME` type instead.

Comment: @Rufinus u're wrong and Michael says the right thing ":" instead of "-" is the answer, I did tested it already. THanks again Michael

Answer (score 2):

'm' is month, you want 'i'

see http://uk.php.net/date

and you should use `date('H:i:s')` instead of the - this is no valid time format.

you could also use `TIME(NOW())` directly in SQL

Comment: +1 for suggesting `TIME(NOW())` (although just `NOW()` will work as well)

Answer (score 0):

[`TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html) is not equivalent to [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html). Set the field appropriately and it should work.

You should also read up on appropriate ways to send time and date data to mysql, as php and mysql deal with time and dates differently.

Comment: There actually is a `TIME` type: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html